# System.IO.Stream in favor of HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webclient, httppostedfilebase

I have a site where I allow members to upload photos.  In the MVC Controller I take the `FormCollection` as the parameter to the Action.  I then read the first file as type `HttpPostedFileBase`. I use this to generate thumbnails. This all works fine.

In addition to allowing members to upload their own photos, I would like to use the `System.Net.WebClient` to import photos myself.

I am trying to generalize the method that processes the uploaded photo (file) so that it can take a general Stream object instead of the specific `HttpPostedFileBase`.

I am trying to base everything off of Stream since the `HttpPostedFileBase` has an `InputStream` property that contains the stream of the file and the `WebClient` has an `OpenRead` method that returns Stream.

However, by going with Stream over `HttpPostedFileBase`, it looks like I am loosing `ContentType` and `ContentLength` properties which I use for validating the file.

Not having worked with binary stream before, is there a way to get the `ContentType` and `ContentLength` from a Stream? Or is there a way to create a `HttpPostedFileBase` object using the Stream?

Answer (score 3):

You're right to look at it from a raw stream perspective because then you can create one method that handles streams and therefore many scenarios from which they come.

In the file upload scenario, the stream you're acquiring is on a separate property from the content-type. Sometimes [**magic numbers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) ([also a great source here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)) can be used to detect the data type by the stream header bytes but this might be overkill since the data is already available to you through other means (i.e. the Content-Type header, or the .ext file extension, etc).

You can measure the byte length of the stream just by virtue of reading it so you don't really need the Content-Length header: the browser just finds it useful to know what size of file to expect in advance.

If your **WebClient** is accessing a resource URI on the Internet, it will know the file extension like http://www.example.com/image.**gif** and that can be a good file type identifier.

Since the file info is already available to you, why not open up one more argument on your custom processing method to accept a content type string identifier like:

```
public static class Custom {

     // Works with a stream from any source and a content type string indentifier.

     static public void SavePicture(Stream inStream, string contentIdentifer) {

        // Parse and recognize contentIdentifer to know the kind of file.
        // Read the bytes of the file in the stream (while counting them).
        // Write the bytes to wherever the destination is (e.g. disk)

        // Example:

        long totalBytesSeen = 0L;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; //1K buffer to store bytes.
        // Read one chunk of bytes at a time.

        do
        {
            int num = inStream.Read(bytes, 0, 1024); // read up to 1024 bytes

            // No bytes read means end of file.
            if (num == 0)
                break; // good bye

            totalBytesSeen += num;  //Actual length is accumulating.

            /* Can check for "magic number" here, while reading this stream
             * in the case the file extension or content-type cannot be trusted.
             */

            /* Write logic here to write the byte buffer to
             * disk or do what you want with them.
             */

        } while (true);

     } 

}
```

Some useful filename parsing features are in the IO namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

Use your custom method in the scenarios you mentioned like so:

From an **HttpPostedFileBase** instance named `myPostedFile`

```
 Custom.SavePicture(myPostedFile.InputStream, myPostedFile.ContentType);
```

When using a **WebClient** instance named `webClient1`:

```
var imageFilename = "pic.gif";
var stream = webClient1.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/images/", imageFilename)
//...
Custom.SavePicture(stream, Path.GetExtension(imageFilename));
```

Or even when processing a file from disk:

```
Custom.SavePicture(File.Open(pathToFile), Path.GetExtension(pathToFile));
```

Call the same custom method for any stream with a content identifer that you can parse and recognize.

Comment: I was trying to stay away from checking the file extension since it's so easy to fake.  However, doesn't look like there's another way.  Thank you!

Comment: You can always use magic numbers if you don't trust the file extension or if it's absent.  In the same way you can't necessarily trust the Content-Type of the browser header. Example of file sigs here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: I just added this magic number table into the answer - it appears to be quite comprehensive: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html